# How to SSL enable my web application?

Tags: web-applications, ssl, tomcat7

I've put the following code in the server.xml file for tomcat:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
    keystoreFile="D:\keystore.jks" keystorePass="****" maxThreads="150"
    port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true"
    sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I have a spring-mvc based web application. But when I try to deploy my app, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Eclipse Workspaces\RPM\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\RPM\WEB-INF\classes\com\rpm\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
```

My web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RPM</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>admin</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>RPM</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd" >

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rpm.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/*"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/*"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/*"/>

    <!-- Beans to be autowired - START-->
    <bean class="com.rpm.beans.Clinic"/>
    <bean class="com.rpm.beans.PatientGroup"/>
    <bean class="com.rpm.beans.Clinician"/>
    <!-- Beans to be autowired - END-->


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" >
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where does Spring has a part in this problem? Did you try to use TLS with a plain war that only contains a "Hello World" JSP?

Comment: @Tichodroma No I didn't try that, but from the error I can get that it has issues trying to access my class files that are deployed. So I though I missed something

Answer (score 2):

The Exception is because of the security manager not about ssl.

Comment: I haven't and I don't have any idea about it. I've added my dispatcher-servlet.xml code, if it can be of any help.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I had accidentally checked the "Enable Security" in the tomcat console that comes up on Eclipse